# With Java NIO, how do you distinguish between clients?

Tags: java, nio

This may be a terribly naive question but I was just wondering if the client would have to send a "client id" of some sort along with every packet to be able to identify who it is from. I couldn't seem to notice any other form of client identification.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear because you haven't provided nearly enough context. If you're talking about TCP/IP networking, each client will still have its own socket...

Comment: Hey Jon, sorry you're right I should have been more specific. It is indeed TCP/IP. I think my understanding of how NIO actually works is still very elementary.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that distinguishing the client (on the client end) via a "client ID" would be a terrible idea, in any context; there's nothing to stop the client from forging a different ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NIO you still have a connection object, the `Channel`. Each channels talk exactly to one client in the same way you would do it with plain `Socket` streams. So you have to identify your client only at the start of the connection.